# elliptic pde question

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Suppose $\Omega$ is a smooth bounded domain in $ R^N$ and suppose  we have

$$-\Delta u(x) = (u(x)_+)^3 \qquad \mbox{ in } D$$
and $$ -\Delta u(x) = (u(x)_-)^3 \qquad \mbox{ in }  \Omega \backslash \overline{D}$$

where $D$ is some unknown open set which is contained in $\Omega$ (assume it has smooth boundary).     Here $ u = u_+ + u_-$ and $ u_+, u_- \ge 0$ (note $u_-$ is not quite the usual negative part of $u$).
Let $\Omega_+:=\{x \in \Omega: u(x)>0 \}$.

Question.  Suppose $u$ is somewhat nice (so assume $ u \in H_0^1(\Omega)$) and maybe a little more. Is $D=\Omega_+$?  (Of course if we take $u$ smooth then this might be trivial by using continuity of $ x \mapsto \Delta u(x)$ and the pde.)

I have tried some (what i consider) natural approaches but I don't seem to be getting anywhere yet I think this is probably a trivial question.